# How to set watchpoints via procfs in Linux?

Tags: linux, watchpoint, procfs

I'm trying to build a debugger-like program
under Linux (Ubuntu) and I've run into some problems.
From what I've heard, the `/proc` vfs provides mechanisms to
create watchpoints, but I can't seem to find out how.

Some man pages pointed me to “control file”s, supposedly located 
at `/proc/<pid>/ctl`, but I can't find this file anywhere.
(Perhaps this file is only for Solaris? Or maybe it's Ubuntu's fault?)

Comment: Where did you find 'some manpage' ?

Comment: well, ctl was mentioned here (http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/816-5174/proc-4?l=ja&a=view).

Answer (score 0):

Under Linux, as far as I know, a debugger will have to call [`ptrace`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace) to attach to the process being debugged, and possibly to influence its behavior.

Looking at the source of [GDB](http://www.gnu.org/s/gdb/) is likely to be helpful.

There is information in `/proc/<pid>` that is of interest to debuggers. For example, [you can read the process's memory via `/proc/<pid>/mem`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6301/how-do-i-read-from-proc-pid-mem-under-linux). You can also [use `ptrace` for this, and you need to use `ptrace` to write](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7706/read-the-stack-of-another-process/9192#9192).